# Civievent live page giving error 500

Tags: civievent, error, php

this isn't really an issue, just a quick PSA. I have the latest wordpress and civicrm 5.66.1. When trying to access civievent live/test registration page, I kept getting an error 500. However, I changed my website to php8.0 and everything seems to be working. It was php8.1 before.
Again, just a heads up for anyone running into this issue.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the error message was exactly. It should be in your log file.

Answer (score 1):

The 55.6.x version has a bug in pear, see at the post of mine
[Illegal argument error](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45798/illegal-argument-error)